# how to call function after MainWindow fully rendered

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like to call a function when the mainwindow is fully rendered. The problem is that if I call a function (here `LoadVideo`) at the end of MainWindow, the function is called but the window is not fully rendered (toolbar or background image is missing). It is fully rendered when `LoadVideo` function is finished. It does the same issue with `CallAfter`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(800,600))
{
    SetIcon(wxIcon("icon.ico", wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO));
    wxBitmap png_1t(wxT("icon-1.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap png_2(wxT("icon-2.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap png_3(wxT("icon-3.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap png_4(wxT("icon-4.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap png_5(wxT("icon-5.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap png_6(wxT("icon-6.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

    menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new wxMenu();
    cameraMenu = new wxMenu();
    toolsMenu = new wxMenu();

    menuBar->Append(fileMenu, _T("&File"));
    menuBar->Append(cameraMenu, _T("&Camera"));
    menuBar->Append(toolsMenu, _T("&Tools"));
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);

    fileMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, _T("Exit"));

    this->SetBackgroundColour(*wxWHITE);

    wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    m_renderWindow = new wxImagePanel(this, wxT("Logo.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);

    sizer->Add(m_renderWindow, 1, wxSHAPED | wxALIGN_CENTER);
    this->SetSizer(sizer);
    this->Layout();

    toolbar->AddTool(10007, _T("ClosedDevice"), png_1);
    toolbar->AddSeparator();
    toolbar->AddTool(10006, _T("Snapshot"), png_2);
    toolbar->AddTool(10001, _T("ContinuousShot"), png_3);
    toolbar->AddSeparator();
    toolbar->AddTool(10002, _T("Pause"), png_4);
    toolbar->AddTool(10003, _T("Record"), png_5);
    toolbar->AddTool(10004, _T("Stop"), png_6);
    
    toolbar->Realize();
    Layout();

    this->GetToolBar()->EnableTool(10006, false);
    this->GetToolBar()->EnableTool(10002, false);
    this->GetToolBar()->EnableTool(10003, false);
    this->GetToolBar()->EnableTool(10004, false);
    this->GetToolBar()->EnableTool(10001, false);

    CallAfter(&MainWindow::LoadVideo, true);
}
```

EDIT :

Solution :

```
Bind(wxEVT_TIMER, [](wxTimerEvent& event) {
  LoadVideo();
});
m_timer.SetOwner(this);
m_timer.StartOnce(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `WxWidget`s use `WM_PAINT` to render, then capture `WM_PAINT` in your message loop, pass it back to the `DefWindowProc`, and then call your function before returning.

(P.S. So much code to achieve something that plain Win32 would achieve in an easier way).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to wait for the window to be repainted before calling `LoadVideo()` until it does something wrong, such as blocking for a noticeably long time -- and, of course, if it does do something like this, the real solution is to change it to stop doing it.

But if you really need to, you can use `CallAfter([this]() { LoadVideo(); })` to call this function during the next event loop iteration, after all the outstanding events (including the `wxEVT_PAINT` one) are processed. This is usually a better idea than do introduce a hard-coded 1s delay.